# How can I export data from azure storage table to .csv file in .Net core C#

Tags: azure-storage

is there an azure API to import/export an existing collection from Azure Table Storage in .csv?

Answer (score 0):

The Table Storage REST API does not provide a response as CSV directly, so it's always necessary to transform the data accordingly, as for example the Azure Storage Explorer does using an [older version of the azcopy v7.3](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-v10#download-azcopy).

I've built a [little C# library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Medienstudio.Azure.Data.Tables.CSV/) that basically does the same. It currently caches all rows in memory though to create the CSV headers so that's something to be aware of.